# Attribute value dependent on equation

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, simple-product

### Attribute A = Attribute B + 10

Is there anyway to create something like the above?  Currently, I have four attributes on which I have to perform the math manually.  I would like to just enter a value into one attribute and have the other attributes update/change/be defined pragmatically.

I don't believe I can be any clearer in my question.

Comment: I found this article, http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/using-a-backend-model-to-customize-magento-a-tip-from-magento-developers-paradise/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set a backend model for the attribute and override beforeSave or afterSave methods in it and update the other attributes there?
Alternatively if you can't modify the source for attribute A, use an observer for model's after_save event.

Comment: See, I had no idea that there was an `afterSave` or `beforeSave`.  Now, that I have something to Google for, is there anything else you could add that would help me?